# Vue.js renders a component only on index.html

Tags: vue.js

I made my first vue.js app and trying to run it on one of the internal pages of a site.  However, it renders only on index.html 
(upd: the component should display a table with some data from mongoDB)

What I'm trying to add to html pages:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <UserComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserComponent from './components/UserComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    UserComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly it displayed to you, or what is the problem ?

Comment: Nothing is displayed (like I didn't add <div id="app"></div>). Only on index.html everything works fine.

Comment: still mis understand you, so it display something or not and if it's displaying something so what behaviour you would expect then ?

Comment: The component should display a table with some data from mongoDB 
(it does, but only on index.html)

Comment: and where you want to display it instead ?

Comment: On mysite.com/datatable.html

Comment: so you need `router` check that https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html